# Text Object in Formula Editor (Crystal Report)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, formula-editor

How can i get the text object so that i can use it in formula editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text objects cannot be read or changed using the Formula Editor within Crystal Reports.  If you want dynamic content that I would suggest using a Formula instead of a Text Object.

Rather bizarrely, you are able change a Text Object value at runtime using .NET

e.g.

`rptObject.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("Text1").Text = "Some dynamic content"`

Comment: I want to get the value of the text object and use it in a formula. Sorry, my question is not clear.

Comment: @EzekielFlores: You can't retrieve the value of a Text Object within the Formula Editor